# How to stack dark mode and peer-checked in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css, darkmode, tailwind-3

I have custom radio buttons and I'm using the tailwind peer and peer-checked to change the background of the label when the radio button is checked , now I need to change the background color of the label when I am dark mode.

```
<input class="radio_input hidden peer" type="radio" id="html"  name="expense_categories_id" value="html">
<label  class="radio_label cursor-pointer  bg-white flex justify-center items-center flex-col text-gray-800 rounded-xl   border-4 border-gray-200 px-4 py-4 peer-checked:bg-gray-800 peer-checked:dark:bg-gray-100 peer-checked:text-white peer-checked:dark:text-gray-600 dark:border-gray-800 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-100 " for="html">Name
</label>
```

Comment: Try to change order of variants from `peer-checked:dark:text-gray-600` to `dark:peer-checked:text-gray-600`